# Downloading and instralling FitGirl repack games

Tags: ubuntu

So i've been struggling with this for about a week now. No matter what i do, i cannot RUN the installed games i got from Fitgirl repacks. Generally, i make a new game in Lutris, set the executable as the .exe installer file, and install using wine as the runner. However, once it finishes, there's nothing. No game files i can find, no executable for the game.
I've tried locating any game files that might've been installed, to no avail. I've tried using different runners, which doesn't work at all. On top of all that, i've scoured every single tutorial i could find, and NONE worked.

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: spend money bro. Easy.